# Combining Tween with frame by frame animation

Tags: android, tween

I'm still having problem with the most basic need.
I wanna have 2 buttons: one runs a tween animation that moves an image 50 pixels, the other button runs a frame by frame animation on that image.

once the tween animation is done, the frame by frame animation runs in the wrong location. weird.
I'm using FillAfter/FillEnabled,

the code to run the tween animation is a basic 
   TranslateAnimation(0, 50, 0 , 0) with the fill after and fillEnabled = true.

the frame by frame code is
   image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resourceId));
   ((AnimationDrawable) image.getDrawable()).start();

help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found of doing it is 
first you move your imageview position, using setLayoutParams with the new margins, 
and only then you start the TranslateAnimation using (-x, -y, 0, 0) so for my specific case in the question, here is my code:

```
TranslateAnimation tweenAnim = new TranslateAnimation(-1 * XStep, -1  * YStep , 0, 0);
tweenAnim.setDuration(number_of_steps * 750);
tweenAnim.setFillAfter(true);
tweenAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
tweenAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

 //layout positioning
lp.leftMargin  += XStep;
lp.bottomMargin += YStep;
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

Log.v(TAG, "leftMargin=" + lp.leftMargin);
Log.v(TAG, "bottomMargin=" + lp.bottomMargin);

imageView.startAnimation(tweenAnim);
```

This was a huge pain. seriously.
thanks for http://www.clingmarks.com/?p=400 I was able to overcome it.